# Convert a list of file paths to a JSON tree in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, json, extjs

I have a NET back-end interacting with Amazon S3 web services. I am using a Javascript library (ExtJs) on the front end to try and create a file-browser. In order to do that I have to convert all the file paths in Amazon like

Directory1/SubDirectory1/File.txt

Directory1/SubDirectory2/File2.txt

Directory2/SubDirectory3/File3.txt

To a JSON tree which would something like this:

```
 root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "Directory1", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "SubDirectory1", children: [
                  {text:"File.txt", leaf: true }
                  ]
                },
                { text: "SubDirectory2",children: [
                  {text: "File2.txt"",leaf: true}
                 ]
               } 
            ] },
            { text: "Director2", expanded: true, children:[
                 {text:"SubDirectory3",children: [
                   {text:"File3.txt",leaf: true}
                     ]
                  }
             ]
             }
    }
```

Anyone know a good way to do this in .NET? Anyway I can think of seems very error prone or heavy on really inefficient.

Comment: post your try first, people will help you make it better ;)

Comment: you could also do this on the client too